# Adding Column SQL Access

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I have a database on MS access and I want to add a new column with an unique ID using SQL.
For example:

```
Name Sales ID
Lucas 20 0.00001
Mike 10 0.00002
John 25 0.00003
```

I'm learning SQL by myself. Can anybody help me, please? :)

Thanks!

Comment: here you show us 3 new records (rows) that you want to add

Comment: If you are wanting to learn the SQL for this then I am pretty sure that to use DDL in ms-access would require you to write it in VBA. You may be better off using something like SQLite or SQL Server Compact.

Comment: actually i have almost 10000 rows and i just want to insert an unique ID, but I must do it using MS access SQL :/

Comment: @TI - you reference to SQLite doesn't make much sense given SQLite's ALTER TABLE support is more not less incomplete than DAO/JET's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming by 'column with an unique ID' you mean an Auto-Number field:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD COLUMN ID AUTOINCREMENT;
```

To then make it the primary key:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD PRIMARY KEY(ID);
```

Comment: So far as I'm aware NOT NULL is implied if you use the AUTOINCREMENT type, though it's harmless (and perhaps better practice) to make it explicit like the other answers do...

Comment: Perfect Chris, thank you! Do you know how can I use this Alter Table on a Linked Table? It shows me an error in that case..

Comment: @lucasserafim No, you cannot alter the structure of a *linked* table from Access. You need to make that change directly to the actual table in the other database, then refresh the table link to make it aware of the change.

Comment: @lucasserafim - Ah, in that case I'm afraid you must use VBA so far as I know, if only to get a DAO Database object (or the ADO equivalent) that you can send SQL statements to.

Comment: Thanks guys, what I will do is convert it to a local table. It would work then for me. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work okay for me in Access 2010:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD COLUMN ID AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL
```

Comment: Quick on the mark! Upvoted for getting there one minute before I could ;-)

Comment: @ChrisRolliston +1 for your answer too. I was going to edit my answer to include the statement to add the PRIMARY KEY, but you beat me to it. :)

Comment: Thanks Gord as well :)

Comment: Could you help me on the question i made to chris too?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
ALTER TABLE "YOUR_TABLE" ADD "FIELD_NAME" UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL DEFAULT NewId()  PRIMARY KEY
```

Comment: it gives me an error "Syntax error in field definition" and marks UNIQUEIDENTIFIER..

Comment: You need change the name of the table ("YOUR_TABLE") and the field name ("FIELD_NAME"). For example:

ALTER TABLE YOUR_TABLE ADD ID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL DEFAULT NewId()  PRIMARY KEY